# ListView not getting updated , where should I call notifyDataSetChanged() and where should i set the adapter?

Tags: android, json, listview

I have written a program to post some json data and get the same json data so that i can show the data in a `ListView` in the same activity.
Posting the data and getting the data is done with the help of volley library.

So my problem is when I type something inside my `EditText` and click on the button to post some data , the data gets posted but I am not able to view it instantly inside my `ListView` , in short data is not getting refreshed instantly inside my `ListView`.I have also tried using `notifyDataSetChanged()` but all in vain.

I am posting my whole activity here , please tell me where exactly i have to set my adapter , my `ArrayList` and the `notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
public class Write_Answers extends ListActivity{
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
ConnectionDetector cd;
TextView txtQuestions;
String questions;
EditText editAnswers;
Button btnAnswer;
String postAnswerUrl = "";
String getAnswerUrl = "";
public String answers;
SessionManager session;
String userType,deviceId,questionId;
ListView lvAnswers;
public static final String TAG_QUESTION_ID = "QId";
public static final String TAG_TRANSACTION_ID = "TransactionId";
public static final String TAG_ANSWERS = "Answer";
public static final String TAG_DATE= "Date";
public static final String TAG_TIME = "Time";
public static final String TAG_DEVICE_ID = "DeviceId";
public static final String TAG_USER_TYPE = "UserType";
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> answersList;
CustomAnswerAdapter customAnswerAdapter;
HashMap<String,String> ans_details_map;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.write_answers);
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
    txtQuestions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textQuestions);
    editAnswers = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtAnswer);
    btnAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer);
    questions = getIntent().getStringExtra("questions");
    txtQuestions.setText(questions);
    answersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    customAnswerAdapter = new 
    CustomAnswerAdapter(Write_Answers.this,answersList);
    lvAnswers = getListView();
    lvAnswers.setAdapter(customAnswerAdapter);
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    questionId = getIntent().getStringExtra("questionsId");
    postAnswerUrl = "http://gps.traxistar.net/PostAnswers.svc/PostAnswers";
    getAnswerUrl =  "http://gps.traxistar.net/GetAnswers.svc/GetAnswers;
```

////////////////////////// get the data from the server the ones which i have to set to the adapter and show in the Listview ///////////////////////

```
    if (isInternetPresent) {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new 
                JsonArrayRequest(getAnswerUrl,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d("Json Array", response.toString());
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                String ques_id = 
                                json.getString(TAG_QUESTION_ID);
                                String trans_id = 
                                json.getString(TAG_TRANSACTION_ID);
                                String device_id = 
                                json.getString(TAG_DEVICE_ID);
                                String ans = json.getString(TAG_ANSWERS);
                                String answerDate = 
                                json.getString(TAG_DATE);
                                String answerTime = 
                                json.getString(TAG_TIME);
                                String userType = 
                                json.getString(TAG_USER_TYPE);
                                ans_details_map = new HashMap<String, 
                                String>();
                                ans_details_map.put(TAG_ANSWERS, ans);
                                ans_details_map.put(TAG_DATE, answerDate);
                                ans_details_map.put(TAG_TIME, answerTime);
                                answersList.add(ans_details_map);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                          customAnswerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                          lvAnswers.setSelection(answersList.size() - 1);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("Volley Error", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Log.d("Error", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
    } else {
        showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection", 
        "You don't have internet connection.",
                false);
    }

    btnAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            answers = editAnswers.getText().toString();
            if (answers.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please write an answer", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if (isInternetPresent) {
                    postAnswers();
                    editAnswers.setText("");
                } else {
                    showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet 
                    Connection", "You don't have internet connection.",
                            false);
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

////////////////////////////// posting the data to the server on button click ////////////////////////////

```
private void postAnswers() {
    Calendar in = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date dt1 = new Date();
    in.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d, yyyy");
    String dateval = sdf1.format(dt1);
    SimpleDateFormat stf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    String timeval = stf1.format(dt1);
    final String date1 = dateval.toString();
    final String time1 = timeval.toString();
    final String datetime = dateval.toString() + "T"
            + timeval.toString();
    final String transId = deviceId + "" + datetime;
    answers = editAnswers.getText().toString();
    List<Map<String, String>> listMap = 
    new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    Map<String, String> answersMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    answersMap.put("TransactionId", transId);
    answersMap.put("DeviceId", deviceId);
    answersMap.put("Answer", answers);
    answersMap.put("QId", questionId);
    answersMap.put("Date", date1);
    answersMap.put("Time", time1);
    answersMap.put("UserType", userType);
    listMap.add(answersMap);

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new 
    JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, postAnswerUrl,
            String.valueOf(new JSONArray(listMap)), new 
            Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                Write_Answers.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answer 
                        posted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.d("Json Response ",response.toString());

            }catch(Exception e){
                //Log.d("JSON Array", response.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //editAnswers.setText("");
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Volley Error", error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse 
        response) {
            try {
                String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                if (response.data == null || response.data.length == 0) {
                    return Response.success(new JSONObject(), 
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                } else {
                    return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                            HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            } catch (JSONException je) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
            }
        }
    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
}
```

Comment: You mean there is a delay in updating the ListView?

Comment: @Jas no delay , i have to either use intent to refresh the activity or go back and come again to this activity to see the updated item

Comment: Where do you get the new data to be displayed?

Comment: i m posting the data to the server and also receving from server , you can there are 2 urls

Comment: specify the code snippet

Comment: i have put comments to show the functionality of the code , please check

Comment: So `customAnswerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` is not working?

Comment: no not at all working

Comment: Are you sure that the data is being fetched at the time you are calling notify?

Comment: when i post some data it does not show at that moment but when i restart the activity or application the listview shows the data

Comment: try my answer and let me know whether it is working

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayAdapter`, `notifyDataSetChanged` only works if you use the `add(), insert(), remove(), and clear()` on the `Adapter`.

When an `ArrayAdapter` is constructed, it holds the reference for the List that was passed in. If you were to pass in a List that was a member of an `Activity`, and change that `Activity` member later, the `ArrayAdapter` is still holding a reference to the original List. The `Adapter` does not know you changed the List in the `Activity`.

I recommend using the the functions of the `ArrayAdapter` to modify the underlying List (`add(), insert(), remove(), clear()`, etc.)

Comment: so notifyDataSetChanged doesnt work with BaseAdapter ?

Comment: Yes it does ... it is in the documentation

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

Any type of update (remove/edit/add) you want to do
(on Post Button click do your posting after that these steps)
 1. update your ArrayList first
 2. remove all views from ListView with previous ArrayList data
 3. call the adapter again with the  updated ArrayList again

hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling notifyDatasetChanged() like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    customAnswerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
}, 3000);
```

and check whether this is working

Comment: should i call this on my button click or while getting the data ?

Comment: After getting your data, you are updating your ListView. so add it after retrieving data